# Google Sheets IMPORTHTML parse error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to use the IMPORTHTML function of Google Spreadsheets.
There is this example by Google itself:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India","table",4)
```

Unfortunately (like all the other examples that I tried), it gives me a parsing error.

I tried some stuff (I am a coder myself) but could not fix it. When I try the exact same line of code on a friends computer it works.

What am I missing here?
My only Idea would be that Google gives me a new Version of Spreadsheets (just like we are all using different Versions of Facebook without noticing). And on this Version i am running on importHTML does not work.

Would be amazing if someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your issue is not `IMPORTHTML()` parse error, but local language setting of your Google Spreadsheet. There are two versions:

- United States version (includes Australia)
- Europe version (pretty much the "rest of the world" version)

Each version has own syntax for formulas:

- **US:** `=IF(A1 = "x", "yes", "no")`
- **EU:** `=IF(A1 = "x"; "yes"; "no")`

While (in most cases - not all cases) US version is able to instantly convert to EU syntax, EU sheet is not able to do so. Language settings can be changed in **File > Spreadsheet settings... > General > Locale**

[image: 5]

Comment: this is excellent, I signed up just to upvote this answer! I was in the same situation and I would have never found on my own... cheers mate!